# How do I rename nlog.config?

Tags: nlog

A while ago, I developed a WPF control and integrated into a third-party solution.

Just my luck, turns out the supplier also now use nlog (v2), which they have registered in the GAC. They don't currently use an `nlog.config` file, although they could do at some point.

I have used nlog v4, which isn't registered in the GAC but resides in the project's output folder instead. I do use an `nlog.config` file.

Two issues I would appreciate your advice with:

1. How would I isolate our nlog config file, can I rename it?
2. Would it be considered good practice to register my `nlog.dll` (v4) in the GAC also?

Comment: you are like to use two NLog configuration isolated in your application? This is possible, but needs some code.

Answer (score 0):

Your second question:

> Would it be considered good practice to register my nlog.dll (v4) in the GAC also?

I would not recommend to use the GAC if it's not required. It makes upgrading more complicated and it's less transparent. NLog 4 is fully semver compliant, so it's easy to upgrade when keeping your nlog.dll in your local bin.